# Merge list of maps into a single map

Tags: elixir

convert a list of maps to a map of maps
**input** ->

```
 [%{"cleiton" => %{"abril" => 346,...}}, %{"pedro" => %{...}}]
```

**output** ->

```
 %{"cleiton" => %{"abril" => 346,...} "pedro" => %{...}}
```

Comment: You should provide a complete example, not `...` which forces people to do extra work to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible way is to use the [`Enum.reduce/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.13/Enum.html#reduce/2) in conjunction with [`Map.merge/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.13.4/Map.html#merge/2), using a map as the accumulator:

```elixir
Enum.reduce(list, &Map.merge/2)
```

Example:

```elixir
iex(1)> list = [%{"cleiton" => %{"abril" => 346}}, %{"pedro" => %{"abril" => 123}}]
[%{"cleiton" => %{"abril" => 346}}, %{"pedro" => %{"abril" => 123}}]
iex(2)> Enum.reduce(list, &Map.merge/2)
%{"cleiton" => %{"abril" => 346}, "pedro" => %{"abril" => 123}}
```

This code basically iterates over the the maps inside `list` and merge them in a new map, hopefully giving the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

[`for`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) comprehension is your friend in such tasks.

```elixir
for map <- [%{"cleiton" => %{"abril" => 346}},
            %{"pedro" => %{"may" => 42}}],
    {key, value} <- Map.to_list(map),
  into: %{},
  do: {key, value}

#⇒ %{"cleiton" => %{"abril" => 346}, "pedro" => %{"may" => 42}}
```